# Getting Table row ID and Values in jQuery Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my web application, I created a table to show some items to the table. In the table, there are nine columns and the last has an editable cell.

[image]

The first column includes the Part_Id related to the Part No record and that field is hidden. So I want to get all the Id and data that does not contain the empty values in the `New Order Qty' column and pass all values to the controller.

So on the `Create Order` button click event, I tried to call this function to took Id and the Order Qty and add them to an array. But only the first record is going to the array.
Is there a way to get only the records that contain values in the `New Order Qty` to array to pass it to the controller?

```
function createOrder() {

  var Orders = new Array();
  $("#tblParts").each(function() {

    var order = {};
    var partId = this.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    var pID = partId.innerText;
    var cellOrder = this.getElementsByTagName("td")[8];
    var cellOrderId = cellOrder.innerText;
    order.Id = pID;
    order.OrderQty = cellOrderId;
    Orders.push(order);

  });
}
```

Comment: First clue `$("#tblParts").each` this would be a problem, because you should never have multiple elements with the same ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. IDs need to be unique
2. You have jQuery, use it

```js
const Orders = $("#tableId tbody tr").filter(function() {
  const cells = $(this).find("td");
  return cells.eq(8).text().trim() != ""
}).map(function() {
  const cells = $(this).find("td");
  return {
    [cells.eq(0).text().trim()]: +cells.eq(8).text()
  }
}).get()

console.log(Orders)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableId">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>QTY</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ID 1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ID 2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ID 3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, @mplungjan Thanks for the code. I'm new to web development. Still struggling in some areas. So in your answer, you showed how to get the values right? Can you guide me to assigning it to the array as well? Because I tried modifying my code using yours and now my code isn't working. Sorry for trubbling you.

Comment: Orders IS an array. the map().get() returns an array